# PCM to AAC conversion take too much time in devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, pcm, aac

I need to convert a linear PCM recorded audio file to AAC format and its working fine too. But in simulator it takes less than 2 Sec but in iPhone4 it is 33Sec and in iPhone 4S it is 51 sec. Its a 6 min audio file. What to do for reducing convertion time in device?? Please help..

Comment: What AAC settings do you use?

Comment: @Flink I am using TPAACAudioConverter wrapper class of Michael Tyson for converting audio... I dont know why its take this much time in devices..

Comment: Probably you can change bitrate to see different results